# Как с помощью хуков при обновлении стейта в родительском компоненте обновить дочерний (нужно обновлять конкретный дочерний, есть атрибут key)

Tags: reactjs, hook

Как можно решить с помощью хуков:

Есть родительский компонент App, есть дочерние Fieldset'ы. В App есть кнопка Add. При нажатии которой отрисовывается Fieldset (филдсетов может быть сколько угодно). У каждого филдсета есть по дефолту пустое поле expression. Из каждого филдсета нужно будет создать объект через API и записать в поле expression полученный id. Функция отправки в родительском компоненте. После отправки я получаю id в родительском компоненте, но не получается обновить значение поля expression в дочернем компоненте. У каждого компонента Fieldset у меня есть key.

```
//Родительский компонент (в нём не весь код, только относящийся к вопросу):
function App() {

const [expression, setExpression] = React.useState('');


function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  getApiData(jsonToCreateCronScheduleEventDateComputer, arrExpression)
    .then((res) => {
      setExpression(res[0].key);
    })
}

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => setArrForms(arrForms.concat(
        <Sett
          key={arrForms.length}
          _id={arrForms.length}
          updateData={handleChange}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          expression={expression}
        />))}>Add</button>
    {arrForms}
    <button
      type="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>

);
}

export default App;

// Дочерний (тоже код не весь):

function Sett(props) {

return (
  <fieldset>
   <input />
   <input />
   <input />


    <div>
      <h2>Result:</h2>
      <span>id выражения:</span> {props.expression ? props.expression : 'test'}
    </div>
  </fieldset>
);
}

export default Sett;
```

Comment: Можно через callback

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён.
Может, кому пригодится:
В родительском компоненте был создан массив объектов, и при добавлении нового объекта сразу добавлялись все пары ключ-значение:

`const [values, setValues] = React.useState([]);`

````
    setValues(
      values.concat([
        {
          id: Date.now(),
          day: "",
          month: "",
          hour: "",
          minute: "",
          year: "",
          currentOrganization: "",
          currentService: "",
          currentServiceSubcategory: "",
          expression: "",
          template: "",
          schedule: ""
        }
      ])
    )
  }```


Далее, если какое-то свойство обновляется, вызывается перерисовка массива:setValues(values.concat([]))
````